# WCF REST WebService - Can't change ServiceContract XML namespace

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, web-services, rest

Kind of new to WCF and everything that surrounds it.

I would like to change the default http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService namespace which is menadatory to my XML based webservice requests to something else, but unfortunately was not able to find anything to solve this.

I've the following:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.mywebservice.com/webservice")]
....
public class WebService
```

But when testing my webservice POST based methods, I still cannot use the new namespace (but the old one still works) for XML based requests. am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Mikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which WCF "REST" flavor framework you are using but if you have your classes marked with the DataContract attribute, set its Namespace property on **each** class to the namespace you want. If they're not marked then add that attribute with your namespace as shown below. This should replace the default namespace being generated for data contracts with your namespace.

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.mywebservice.com/webservice")]
public class YourDataClass
{
     //something applicable...
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks!
Actually I just figured it out myself, but I appreciate your help nontheless.
Is there a way to change the "default" behaviour so I won't have to do the above in every class i'm serializing? also, I've noticed that response which are "basic types" such as boolean or an int, are returned with the default "microsoft" namespace, is there any way to change that?

Comment: WCF allows more control over the soap formatting if you use the MessageContract instead of the DataContract attribute. I know you can set the [MessageBodyMember attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagebodymemberattribute.aspx) namepace but I don't think that will apply to the actual type of the member. From what I remember, the generated WSDL usually defines basic types in terms of XSD supported types. I haven't seen MS namespaces used for XSD types before. You may want to start a new question with examples to change that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot your using the WCF REST stuff so my previous comment probably doesn't apply to your case and you're stuck with whatever MS is generating for your XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Namespace on both the ServiceContract attribute on the interface and the ServiceBehavior attribute on the implementation class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://www.mywebservice.com/webservice")]
public class WebService
```

Comment: Sorry, But i'm not using an interface... I simply have the above class, and I use the Global.asax file to register the service with a specific route...
I tried using the "ServiceBehavior" namespace attribute but it still didn't work...

Comment: I guess the new WCF REST is different enough from the old SOAP-based WCF. Might be a bug. You might try posting something to Glenn Block's blog.